# Equivalent to true==true or 1==1 in Lucene query syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

In some query languages you sometimes create, at first, weird-looking constructs like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE 1=1
```

(the `1=1` part)

This is not a question about if and when you should do this but there can be multiple reasons like a configurable UI or something like that.

My question is, does Lucene query syntax offer something similar. I have tried doing the following in a query string query in Elasticsearch:

```
1:1
true:true
```

It doesn't return anything and in that case, I would like it to find everything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you're using `query_string`, you should try `*` ;-)

Comment: There are multiple ways to get all. `*:*` being another. The point here is that I want a checkbox somewhere and the value of one of the sides will be true or false (or 0 or 1). So possible queries can be `1:0` and `1:1`. Makes sense?

Comment: @ThomasArdal it makes sense. I am trying to do the same thing. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @doug144 No, I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple option is using `match_all` , but there is also a  limit of a query result set max_result_window  is defined at index level (The default is 10K): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html

so it might not return all the possible results.

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: I know about `match_all`, `size`, etc. What I'm looking for is the construct for query string query. Thanks.